# Google Maps/ OpenLayers only rendering top left tiles

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, rendering

I'm seeing a weird issue with Google Maps and OpenLayers. When loading a page as shown below, only the two top-left tiles render, leaving the rest of the map blank.

I looked in the Network tab in Chrome Dev. Tools, and indeed, those are the only two tiles that came down the pipe.

However, once I interact with the map using the mouse in any way, the tiles all come down properly. Rendering the map using Bing or any other provider works fine.

One likely possibility: the map is rendered on a tab widget. If I explicitly load that tab in the URL (e.g. specifying #tab-4), the map renders fine.

Also, I've seen people having this problem when they don't explicitly specify the dimensions of the map div in pixels, but mine is explicitly set.

The behavior is identical in Firefox, IE 9, and Chrome.

Anyone seen this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Post your code.  Try to strip out as much of the unrelated stuff (e.g. pop-ups or things around your map)

Comment: Here's the code with the extra stuff stripped out: https://gist.github.com/3499702.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs always when you initialize the map in invisible part of the website (ie: ). I had the same when working with jQuery accordion. No matter if it is OpenLayers or Google Maps API v3.

I think it is a bug from google.

As far as I remember I solve it by initialization of map during tab opening

Comment: Odoakr, can you explain how to do this, i have no tabs or I don't know for them.

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933005/913295

```
var idleListener = this.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(this.rootScope.map, 'resize');
  google.maps.event.removeListener(idleListener);
});
```